# Laravel ANY artisan commands return "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function report()"

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm finding myself in a weird situation where any command I give to "artisan" it returns an error, even `php artisan` alone:

```
PHP Fatal error: 

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function report() on null in /Users/myusername/ProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:367
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/myusername/ProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#1 /Users/myusername/ProjectName/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 {main} thrown in /Users/myusername/ProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php on line 367
```

I've not touched the `vendor/laravel` folder and tried updating to latest Laravel version so I suppose this error is not something I'm creating with wrong code but something other I don't really get.

It's saying the error is here:

```
//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php

protected function reportException(Exception $e)
{
    $this->app[ExceptionHandler::class]->report($e);
}
```

I've tried updating Laravel, but with on luck. So I even upgraded and got the same result. What could be causing it?

Comment: Have you created a custom exception?

Comment: Thank you for the interest, no I did not create any custom Excecption Class

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your web.php or api.php

Comment: Syntax error or smth like this, because it may cause this issue too

Comment: comment your vendor folder and fire `composer update`. Have you made changes in any config folder files?

Comment: Can you please confirm the using previous and later laravel version?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the error is thrown when you set a `__construct()` inside `app/Console/Kernel.php`